# Fedora 19 using KDE - Phonon cannot switch to hdmi audio device 7

Tags: audio, kde, pulseaudio, hdmi

I have an issue with HDMI sound.

I recently upgraded to **Fedora 19 (clean install)** but this issue exsists on F18 too.
I have Intel **DQ67SW** motherboard with integrated audio/video and ASUS-**NVidia GT220** VGA card.
Both the MB and the VGA have HDMI output but **Phonon** will only find the first HDMI on the MB regardless of it is used or not.
I have only one Monitor with speakers and of course it’s connected to the VGA card.

I use Fedora 19 with KDE.

Strange thing that when I switch to Gnome the sound will work. **If I switch back, KDE will also work** but the sound configuration UI won’t list the proper device in the selection. If I change the selection the sound will fail immediatel on the change, even if I click on Cancel.

**Now I have to install Gnome to manage the sound settings only!**

As far as I see **it’s user specific configuration** and located somewhere in the home directory. I tried to save various sound related files (e.g. pulse, libphonon.something), but none of them helped.

Can anybody explain me this behavior?

I red about that Phonon has issues with multiple HDMI outputs but it's somehow forcible to have a secondary one.

I want to have a proper workaround (without Gnome) with which I can control the sound settings.

I used to configure asound.conf even with plugs and redirections but couple of kernel updates ago it won’t work. And AFAIK KDE use Pulseaudio, not Alsa.

I didn’t mentioned that before one of the kernel updates I didn’t have any sound issues. I can’t remember the exact version.

[update 2014-04-30]

---

Here's the list of audio devices:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `/etc/asound.conf`

```
pcm.softvolPhonon {
 type softvol
 slave.pcm "default:CARD=0"
 control {
     name "HDMI"
     card 0
 }
 min_dB -51.0
 max_dB 0.0
 resolution 100
 hint {
     show on
     description "hdmi with extra Volume Control"
 }
}
```

You need to replace card 0 with the hdmi audio output in you system.

Comment: Does not help. See update